# Почему вместе с нужным листом 4, сохраняются все 20 листов при сохранение файлов Excel?

Tags: python, pandas, excel, openpyxl

**Задача**: Есть шаблон файла с `20` разными таблицами для отчёта, нужно заполнить их все, используя различную логику. Я прописываю её на pandas. Далее покажу свою проблему, на примере отчёта `4`:

Есть `файл1`, в котором содержится информация по деньгам и проектам. `Файл2`, который содержит `20` разных шаблонов отчётов.

**Мои действия:** Открываю шаблон, произвожу необходимые вычисления с данными из `файла1`, записываю в новый файл `Result` (Важно, чтобы сохранялось исходное форматирование таблиц и шрифтов, поэтому использую `openpyxl`, а не `pandas`, для чтения и записи шаблона).

**Проблема**: при выполнении этого скрипта, создаётся новый файл `Result.xlsx`, в нём всё правильно посчитано и сохранено исходное форматирование, но вместе с нужным листом 4, сохраняются все `20` листов исходных отчётов из `файла2`. И если я запущу аналогичный скрипт для отчёта `5`, то он сотрёт все предыдущие посчитанные отчеты и сохранит только отчёт `5` и `20` остальных пустых листов из `файла2`.

А в итоге мне нужно прогнать все `20` скриптов, чтобы они сохранили и посчитали `20` отчётов в файле `Result`. (т.е. нужно не перезаписывать этот файл, а просто добавлять к нему новый лист с вычислениями соответствующего скрипта)

```
import pandas as pd
from tqdm import tqdm
import openpyxl

def tablica4():
# Загружаем первый файл
file1 = pd.read_excel(r"C:\1\2\3\4\5\6\File1.xlsx",
                      sheet_name="File1")

# Открываем шаблон
workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename='Отчет_шаблон.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook["4"]
workbook.active = worksheet

# Условия для фильтрации данных. Код строки
kod_3 = file1 .loc[file1 ['Тип'] == "Тип1"]
kod_4 = file1 .loc[file1 ['Тип'].isin(("Тип2", "Тип3"))]

# Суммируем поступления по фильтрованному столбцу
kod_3_4 = kod_3['Сумма'].sum() / 1000
kod_4_4 = kod_4['Сумма'].sum() / 1000
kod_2_4 = kod_3_4 + kod_4_4
kod_1_4 = kod_2_4

# Подсчитаем уникальные проекты
kod_3_3 = len(kod_3['ID'].unique())
kod_4_3 = len(kod_4['ID'].unique())
kod_2_3 = kod_3_3 + kod_4_3
kod_1_3 = kod_2_3

# Записываем данные в ячейки таблицы
worksheet['D8'].value = kod_3_4
worksheet['D9'].value = kod_4_4
worksheet['D7'].value = kod_2_4
worksheet['D6'].value = kod_1_4

worksheet['C8'].value = kod_3_3
worksheet['C9'].value = kod_4_3
worksheet['C7'].value = kod_2_3
worksheet['C6'].value = kod_1_3

workbook.save("Result.xlsx")


tablica4()
```

**P.S**. Пробовал различные варианты сохранения, и при использовании pandas всё сохраняется и работает отлично, но слетает исходное форматирование файла шаблона, а мне оно нужно. Поэтому решил использовать `openpyxl`, он сохраняет форматирование и удобно работает, просто видимо я упускаю какой-то важный момент.

Comment: Исправьте, пожалуйста отступы в коде. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вообще судя по описанию и коду всё работает так как я бы и ожидал:

1. вы открываете файл шаблона: `workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename='Отчет_шаблон.xlsx')`
2. выбираете конретный лист: `worksheet = workbook["4"]`
3. модифицируете его (при этом все остальные листы шаблона на месте)
4. затем сохраняете его как новый файл `workbook.save("Result.xlsx")`

Логично что каждый раз результат перезатирается пустым шаблоном с единственным модифицированным листом. В данном случае непонятно, каким же образом у вас всё корректно работает в случае `pandas`

Я бы предположил что правильно было бы так:

1. открыть файл шаблона
2. скопировать из него лист в новую книгу `Result.xlsx`
3. модифицировать уже его там
4. сохранить результат

Таким образом у вас в `Result.xlsx` будут последовательно добавлятся листы с данными.

Другой вариант разово копировать шаблон в `Result.xlsx` и далее работать только  ним, суть думаю понятна.